# How can i know my FSharpPowerPack version?

Tags: makefile, compilation, f#, functional-programming

Im trying to compile some files with this MakeFile :

```
FSPPHOME=/opt/FSharpPowerPack-4.5.0.0
FSC=fsharpc

all:    Program.exe

SqlLexer.fs:    SqlLexer.fsl
    mono $(FSPPHOME)/bin/fslex.exe SqlLexer.fsl --unicode

SqlParser.fs:   SqlParser.fsp
    mono $(FSPPHOME)/bin/fsyacc.exe SqlParser.fsp --module SqlParser

SqlParser.fsi:  SqlParser.fsp

SOURCES=Sql.fs SqlParser.fsi SqlParser.fs SqlLexer.fs

Program.exe:    $(SOURCES) Program.fs
    $(FSC) --reference:$(FSPPHOME)/bin/FSharp.PowerPack.dll $(SOURCES) Program.fs

LexerOnly.exe:  $(SOURCES) LexerOnly.fs
    $(FSC) --reference:$(FSPPHOME)/bin/FSharp.PowerPack.dll $(SOURCES) LexerOnly.fs

clean:
    rm -f Program.exe SqlParser.fsi SqlParser.fs SqlLexer.fs
```

But when i try to make my Makefile i get this error:

```
error FS0078: Unable to find the file '/opt/FSharpPowerPack-4.5.0.0/bin/FSharp.PowerPack.dll' in any of
 /usr/lib/mono/4.5
```

I believe that if i know the version of FSharpPowerPack then i can set the MakeFile to match it ... I dont know if this is a solution.

Comment: I think you'll be better off using [ProjectScaffold](http://fsprojects.github.io/ProjectScaffold/) for your F# projects: it gives you a setup with a lot of the behind-the-scenes building stuff already done for you. All you have to do is follow the Project Scaffold instructions (be sure to read about using Paket for dependency management, as that would have solved a lot of the problems you're having) and you should be fine.